# Lag in Photon Game, Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I just created a simple test game in unity using Photon and am experiencing a lot of chop. I have tried setting interpolation in the Photon View settings but that doesn't help. I would expect that if i only have two connections lag and chop should not be an issue. Please let me know what I should be doing.

My Ping is around 160. Don't know if that is causing something.

Here is a video of chop:

https://youtu.be/I9_bg8YQzy4

Comment: server and the two clients in the video on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. they are. Using localhost

Comment: So the ping is the average time it takes for the packet to reach the server from a client and back? Just trying to figure out why it is 160 on localhost.